# How to Mock a trackable repository?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I am doing unit testing for the first time.I want to mock a Trackable Repository. Is it different from mocking normal repository? I am in doubt because I was creating a simple repository and my method to be tested which uses trackable repository  was not accepting it. Can u provide a simple example to mock a trackable repository.
I am passing the repository like this using DI:

```
   public CountryService(ITrackableRepository<Country> repository) : base(repository)
    {
    }
```

and I want to test if the country is inserted by the Upsert Method:

```
public void UpsertCountries(Country[] countries)
        {
            countries.ToList().ForEach(country =>
            {
                if (Repository.Queryable().Any(c => c.ForeignId == country.ForeignId))
                {
                    UpdateCountry(country);
                }
                else
                {
                    Repository.Insert(country);
                }
            });
        }
```

Thanks in advance....

Comment: What's a "Trackable Repository"? How were you setting it up that was not working?

Comment: Show us your code and what you want to test

Answer (score 1):

```
[Test]
public void YourTest()
{
    //Arrange
    var mockRepo = new Mock<ITrackableRepository<Country>>();
    var service = new CountryService(mockRepo.Object);
    var countryArray = new Country[]{};
    //Act
    service.UpdateCountry(countryArray);
    //Assert
    mockRepo.Verify(repo => repo.Insert(It.IsAny<Country>()), Time.Once);
}
```

If you want to setup some behaviour to you repo you can do it in this way:

```
mockRepo.Setup(repo => repo.PropertyName).Returns(//return something)
```

Hope it will give you some insights